# JoinAcross with multiple associations

Tags: list-manipulation, built-in-symbols

I would like to use JoinAcross to combine several lists of associations.  Extending an example from the documentation, I'd like to do this:

```
JoinAcrossList[{{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>}, {<|a -> 1, c -> Y|>}, {<|a -> 1,
 e -> Z|>}}, Key[a]]
```

Of course, this fails.  I have a way of doing this but am wondering if there is anything built-in that would do it or perhaps a more efficient way.

My solution is to use this:

```
JoinAcrossList[{{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>}, {<|a -> 1, c -> Y|>}, {<|a -> 1, e -> Z|>}}, Key[a]]
```

Where

```
JoinAcrossList[associations_List, joinKey_] := Fold[JoinAcross[#1, #2, joinKey] &, associations[[1]], Drop[associations, 1]];
```

The above example gives this:

```
In[]:= JoinAcrossList[{{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>}, {<|a -> 1, 
c -> Y|>}, {<|a -> 1, e -> Z|>}}, Key[a]]

Out[]= {<|a -> 1, b -> X, c -> Y, e -> Z|>}
```

Which is the desired result.  It also works for the case where the list contains only two elements such as this example:

```
JoinAcrossList[{{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>}, {<|a -> 1, c -> Y|>}}, Key[a]]
```

As I write this, I realize that a more efficient combination would probably split this into multiple pairs and then perform successive combinations of those.  Would be nice to have a built-in function for this if the number of elements in the list is large.

I can see how to divide a list of elements into pairs using something like the following but not yet sure how to evaluate starting at the lowest elements and then building back up.

```
NestWhile[Partition[#, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}] &, Range[11],Ceiling[Length[#]/2] != 1 &]
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to do an efficient implementation of the function `JoinAcrossList`?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this with some built in operators.  What I have works.

Comment: Just as a small tip: `Fold[f, list]` is equivalent to `Fold[f, First[list], Rest[list]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

```
JoinAcrossList1[list_, key_] := Fold[JoinAcross[#1, #2, key] &, list][[1]]

JoinAcrossList1[{{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>}, {<|a -> 1, c -> Y|>}, {<|a -> 1, e -> Z|>}}, Key[a]]
```

> <|a -> 1, b -> X, c -> Y, e -> Z|>

This uses binary subdivision and recursion, but I doubt that it will be faster.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[list_, key_] /; Length[list] == 1 := list;
f[list_, key_] /; Length[list] == 2 := {JoinAcross[list[[1]], list[[2]], key]};
f[list_, key_] := f[
  Join[
   f[list[[;; Quotient[Length[list], 2]]], key],
   f[list[[Quotient[Length[list], 2] + 1 ;;]], key]
   ],
  key
  ]
JoinAcrossList2[list_, key_] := f[list, key][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: I like what you wrote but as you suspected, it isn't actually faster.  Will post some timings.

Comment: For 3 elements to the list: 0.00007 for JoinAcrossList2 and 0.000049 for JoinAcrossList.  For 4 elements, where I would think that the split might help, 0.000091 for JoinAcrossList2 and 0.000064 for JoinAcrossList.